# Where does a function declared in .h file find the its definition?

Tags: c, compilation

I'm new to C programming and I have questions about the header files inclusion part.

(1) I know that by convention, a header file shouldn't include function definitions. But in this simple code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("123");
}
```

`printf` function is declared in `stdio.h`, however I didn't manually define the `printf` function. Why does the code compile successfully? Shouldn't it throw a compilation error something like `function printf is not defined`?

(2) Suppose that I have a `foo.h` header file, which declares function `foo`

```
int foo(int num);
```

I have a `main.c` file below in the same directory as `foo.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
int main(){
    printf("%d",foo(123));
}
```

My question is where should I define function `foo`? Is there any other place besides inside `main.c`?

If not, what's the point of using header files? Because in my mind, it's like: every time we want to implement a function declared in a header file, we have to define it in the `.c` file.
Why not define (and thus declared) function `foo` in `main.c`, directly?

Comment: Function `foo()` is found by the compiler and linker where it has been told by the **make** process, and the exact mechanism varies with the compiler and environment. Similarly the linker is told, or already knows, where the standard library function `printf()` can be found. The declarations in the header files are so that the functions are interfaced correctly by the calling code.

Comment: After declaring `foo()` in `foo.h`, I defined `foo()` in `foo.c`, my IDE (or should I say linker?) successfully finds that: `foo()` definition was in `foo.c` when compiling main program.     I then renamed the definition file `foo.c` into `bar.c`, my IDE can't find the definition and throws an error. Should I always name the definition `.c` file the same as the declaration header file?

Answer (score 4):

> If not, what's the point of using header files? Because in my mind, it's like: every time we want to implement a function declared in a header file, we have to define it in the `.c` file. Why not define (and thus declared) function `foo` in `main.c`, directly?

Real projects can grow to have hundreds or even thousands of different functions and keeping them all in the same source file rapidly becomes untenable.  Instead, we group them into separate source files that can be compiled independently into *object* files (machine code, but not executable on their own), and then those object files can be *linked* into an executable file (or a library that can be linked into other projects, such as the standard C libraries).

Separate compilation has a number of benefits:

- Different parts of an application can be tested independently of each other;
- Code can be easily shared between different projects;
- Parts of an application can be re-implemented without affecting other parts.

You must declare a function before you call it so the compiler can determine that you're calling the function *correctly* (passing the right number and types of arguments and using the result appropriately).  If the function is defined in a different source file from the caller, it’s often a good idea to put the declaration in a separate header, so instead of manually retyping the declaration in every source file that calls that function, you just `#include` the header file containing that declaration.

It's also common to define new types (such as the `FILE` type) and macros (such as the `NULL` macro) in header files so those definitions can easily be `#include`d and used by your code.

It’s kind of hard to see the utility until you work on a sizable project.

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of header files is to declare functions and variables defined in one module to be used in another unrelated module.

In your second example, you could create foo.c with the following contents:

```
int foo(int num)
{
    return num * 4;
}
```

Then you would compile both foo.c and main.c:

```
gcc -c foo.c
gcc -c main.c
```

Then link them:

```
gcc -o my_program foo.o main.o
```

If you tried to compile and link only main.c, you'd get a linker error stating that the definition of `foo` could not be found.

When you have a large project, you'll typically want to break up functions into multiple files, with related functions together in one .c file.

For functions declared in stdio.h, these are part of the *standard C library*.  The definitions for these functions are automatically linked in so you don't have to do so explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the code compile successfully?

Because your compiler automatically links standard C library. The standard C library contains the definition of `printf` function.

> Shouldn't it throw a compilation error something like function printf is not defined?

No, the compiler is required to provide definitions for standard symbols and `printf` is one of them (in a hosted environment).

> My question is where should I define function foo?

*Anywhere* you want. In `main.c` or in another `.c` file you want. Typically, a good practice, I would expect `foo` to be defined in `foo.c`, because it's declaration is in `foo.h`.

> Is there any other place besides inside main.c?

Yes, in another *translation unit* - in another `.c` file. For example in `foo.c`.

> If not, what's the point of using header files?

A long, long time ago computers weren't as fast as they are today - but still these computers had C language. Because it was impossible for historic compilers to parse all function definition in one big file, because for example of limited memory available at that time, for speed of compilation defining a symbol was splitted into smaller units. Symbol declaration were placed in one file, definitions in another. That way compilers compile small `.c` files that see only short `.h` files containing only smaller amount of information, then after compiling it in a separate stage the linker links all pre-compiled `.c` files together. That way compilation uses less resources at a time.

Nowadays, newer progarmming languages just don't care - when you write like `import` in these languages the compiler works as-if it extracts declarations from definitions. Computer are fast and powerful enough to handle that with ease. With newest addition of `module`s in C++, the C++ community is hoping to get a similar mechanisms.

> Why not define (and thus declared) function foo in main.c, directly?

Dividing symbols definitions between source files is a matter of quality. We programmers divide information into smaller pieces and place them in separate files to easier manage big programs. But, sure,  why not - if it's a small program, just do it in a single file, there are many programs written in a single `.c` file (that is very long, ex. more then 3000 lines).

Comment: `No, the compiler is required to provide definitions for standard symbols and printf is one of them (in a hosted environment).` compiler does not have to provide any definitions. They have to be present in the object files or libraries used by the linker.

Comment: I think I meant there "the compiler" as everything, the whole "thing", the whole implementation, anything that takes part in translating source code into the resulting executable, so including the linker and anything else.

Answer (score 2):

> printf function is declared in stdio.h, however I didn't manually
> define the printf function. Why does the code compile successfully?
> Shouldn't it throw a compilation error something like function printf
> is not defined?

Compiler emits the code which calls the `printf`. It does not check if the function is in other compilation units or object files. The compiler has only to know what the `printf` is - ie what is the return type and the parameters of the function. Later the `linker` links the object files and libraries and finds if the `printf` is somewhere there. Because you link towards the standard library - the compiled `printf` function is there and the linking is successful. If linker will not find the function (or generally object) in the object files and libraries, it will emit an error.

> My question is where should I define function foo? Is there any other
> place besides inside main.c?

Anywhere. In any compilation unit. The important part is that the generated object file containing `foo` code (definition) has to passed to the linker.

If your function has not external linkage (ie is declared as `static`) its definition has to be in the same compilation unit (file) as the calling function.

Example:

```
static void foo(int n);

int main(void)
{
    foo(123);
}

static void foo(int n)
{
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

Comment: Elaborating on "anywhere, in any compilation unit" a bit: One widely used convention is to declare some types and functions inside `foo.h` and implement those functions declared in `foo.h` in `foo.c`. Another convention (used in some libraries) is to implement each function `bar()` inside `bar.c` while having the declarations grouped inside a topic specific header file. Other conventions are available. Choose a convention adequate for your project, then use it consistently.

Comment: @ndim After declaring `foo()` in `foo.h`, I defined `foo()` in `foo.c`. When compiling the main program, my IDE (or should I say linker?) successfully finds that: `foo()` definition was in `foo.c`. I then renamed the definition file `foo.c` into `bar.c`, my IDE can't find the definition and throws an error. Should I always name the definition .c file the same as the declaration header file?

Comment: No it does not matter what the C file name is.

Comment: @o_yeah IDEs try dealing with some of the complexity of building code by adding a lot more complexity to make usage easier in some usage scenarios. How you tell your IDE how to link your program (that includes what compilation units your program consists of) is impossible to tell without knowing what that IDE is and knowing that specific IDE on a more than basic level.